# C++ passing "default" struct to function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how I can "pass default struct values" to a function without initializing the struct, this is what I have now:

```
struct Color3i
{
    Color3i(): r(255), g(255), b(255) { }
    int r, g, b;
};

void CCore::Color(Color3i color)
{
    double red, green, blue;
    red = color.r / 255.0f;
    green = color.g / 255.0f;
    blue = color.b / 255.0f;

    glColor3f(red,green,blue);
}

Color3i defaultColor;
Core.Color(defaultColor);
```

What I'm trying to do would look like this but this clearly doesn't work:

```
Core.Color(Color3i defaultColor);
```

How would I pass the struct to the function without initializing it with Color3i defaultColor; is this possible?

Sorry if this has been asked before but I tried searching the interwebs but I couldn't find anything (maybe I'm using the wrong keywords to search)

Comment: What's the problem here? That looks like it should do what you want. What values for `color.r` are you getting?

Comment: I take it you are trying to avoid having to use the line `Color3i defaultColor;` and passing that variable to the function?

Comment: You should be able to use `Core.Color(Color3i());`

Comment: Respect to  `red = color.r / 255.0f`: the numerator is an `int`, the denominator a `float`, and the assigned-to type a `double`. Not an immediate concern but mixing types like this can give you gyp.

Comment: @Bathseba Thanks for the input, I was wondering myself if there was also a problem in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to do this:

```cxx
Core.Color(Color3i());
```

That is, call the default constructor to initialize a new instance, and pass it.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. I have C++ classes in school but I've been doing programming on freetime on my own. We haven't got in to structs or such yet

Comment: By the way, it's bad form to start your variable names with a capital letter: the language and compiler don't care at all, but other programmers reading your code will expect `Core` to be a type name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. CCore is one of my classes, I define Core in as CCore Core (Core handles rendering and inputs in my app). I've been basically reading articles on the internet and went with them, confusing at times since some articles recommend something and others recommend something else, but both produce same results. And after internet research seems like our teacher is introducing C# in our C++ lessons for some reason, makes it even confusing as I'm trying to stay purely C++

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to pass an information that you want the color to be default. The simplest one is given in the comments already:

```
Core.Color(Color3i())
```

If you want the code to be shorter, you can set the default value in the function parameter you invoke:

```
void CCore::Color(Color3i color = Color3i()) { ... }

....
Core.Color(); //no argument = default
```

If you want to be more descriptive instead, you can create a static function acting as a constructor in the `Color`:

```
struct Color3i {
    Color3i(): r(255), g(255), b(255) { }
    int r, g, b;
    static Colo3i defaultColor() { return Color3i(); }
};
...
Core.Color(Color3i::defaultColor());
```

Finally, if you want to control the context where the default color can be used, you can create a new dummy enum type and overload the function(s) to accept the default version explicitly:

```
enum DefaultColorEnum {
    DefaultColor
};

void CCore::Color(Color3i color) {
    ... //normal code
}

void CCore::Color(DefaultColorEnum) { //ignore the parameter value, the type is what matters
    Color(Color3i()); //invoke the generic version with default value
}

...

Core.Color(DefaultColor);
```

It all depends on what you actually wants to achieve...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. I have C++ in school but we haven't got very far yet. I've been doing programming on my own at freetime. Maybe I'm way over my head at some aspects in C++ but I'm atleast really interested in it heh